# Migrate from svn to git gives me 0r, master, remotes/git-svn

Tags: git, migration, svn-trunk

After I migrated from SVN to GIT

> git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project -T trunk -b branches -t tags

This command has converted from svn to GIT as I have checked history by "gitk" command.

But this is incorrect when

> git branch -r which gives me like git-svn
>
> git branch --all gave me like this structure
>
> `0r
>   * master
>     remotes/git-svn`

Can anyone help me?

When I checked its structure by gitk,

> Branches: 0r, master, remotes/git-svn

Comment: Why on earth is this tagged with grails?

Comment: i am new and am not good at this. can u help me with this?